# Magento: How to get user role from user id

Tags: magento

I am building a custom admin extension, I need to find a user's role having it's ID, any way to do this, I've been trying to find where does magento store the info on what users are what role with no luck so far. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The user's ID or the role's ID?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the users who log into the admin console, this should get you what you want.

```
//By ID
$id = 2;
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id)->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);

//By Username
$username = 'admin';
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);
```

Comment: Dear how can get user role by user_id in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 6):

Using this code you will get the role of current user

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
$role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

By using this code you will get the detail of the user and also it's role data

```
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->
     getCollection()-addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->
     getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
$role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
```